# 'ComboBoxItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to use the following piece of code in my program:

```
 for (int i = 1950; i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
            {
                ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBox();
                item.Content = i;
                comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

but I get the error message "The type or namespace name 'ComboBoxItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
I am pretty sure this is because I am not using WPF, so what would be the equivalent to calling ComboBoxItem in winforms?

Comment: ComboBox accepts any kind of object, it uses the object's ToString() method to display the item.  You'd consider a plain string first.

Comment: Why do you have `ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBox();` there? Are you trying to create a new ComboBox in the loop (very unusual), or to add values to an existing ComboBox (very common)? A weird hybrid thing came out, also because `ComboBoxItem` is WPF stuff (and of course it's not a ComboBox). Did you copy pieces of code from somewhere?

Comment: I figured out the issue, I needed to remove the lines `ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBox();` and `item.Content = i;` and instead just use `comboBox1.Items.Add(i);`